# Can you view only the latest tweet from all of the people who you follow?

Tags: twitter

I am looking for a way to view only the latest tweet of my followers. Often, because I follow a lot of people, my home feed is very busy.

Short of clicking through to their profiles, is there an application or trick to only see the last tweet of everyone you follow?

Comment: Just to check - do you want the latest tweet from your *followers* or following?

Comment: Following. Sorry, I fixed the question title.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on a webapp to do just this.  I find it frustrating too that if I check say once a day, and some of my followees have posted a ton that they clutter up the stream and I miss the *one* important update from someone that rarely posts

My solutions so far have been:

- Create separate lists for "low posters" and check those lists manually (a bit of a pain in the twitter app on phones, but relatively easy with multiple columns in Tweetdeck)
- Prior to that, using Filttr to at least block out tweets that contained username *and* 4sq (for example) for people who just always check in at places.

In the end the twitter lists ended up being the better solution for me, but no, I have not yet found a web app that really gives "weight" to tweets the way I would prefer

Comment: That seems like an easy enough application to structure. First, just create a list of people who the user follows, then ping each feed for the latest one. The bottleneck I see here is the daily API call limit.